Aggregating by geometry using ArcGIS Pro
I am trying to get the sum of an attribute for overlapping features that have the same geometry yet they are individual features.
In QGIS I could use the Sum Line Lengths tool. In ArcGIS Pro this tool is called "sumarize within" ... https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/summarize-within.htm
Furtmermore there is the join by location tool. But unfortunately it only generates features with a join count = 1. 
The input at this location here is 10 features with the same geometry.
The desired result should be single feature with the shared geometry and the summarized values of a certain column.
My current workaround is:

create a buffer around each feature of the original dataset
use this buffer polygons to summarize within


Just to clarify when you say they have "the same geometry", is it ALWAYS the scenario that your stacked lines are the same geometry or do you get partial overlaps? If you have partial overlaps then do you need to apportion the value of interest? If they are always exactly the same and simply stacked on top of each other then you could create a table grouping them using the Find Identical and then join that group value by FID and then run a simply summary stats tool.

they are always identical.
